# typeof(T)を使って任意の型と比較する事は可能でしょうか？

Tags: c#, unity3d

Tがレスポンスの型として渡ってくるメソッドがあり、
レスポンスが無い時は、TはNullDataクラスとなり
レスポンスがある時は、Tは任意の型クラスとなります。

レスポンスが無い時は、NullDataクラスとなるので、
下記のようなIF文で比較したのでIFの中に入ってきませんでした。

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(NullData))
```

Tを指定した型と比較するにはどのようにすれば良いでしょうか？

環境：Unity5.5.1.f1、C#4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C#仕様としては可能ですしWindows環境であれば普通に動作します。
意図通りの動作をしないとしたら、Unity側の問題と推測されます。

Comment: 私の環境だけのようなので、ログの細分化と環境を合わせて再度テストしてみます。

Answer (score 0):

T 型のオブジェクトがメソッドの引数  `T obj` で渡されてくるのなら

```
if (obj is NullData)
```

とかではダメなのでしょうか？

Answer (score -1):

.NET Frameworkならばあるバージョンからは operator == が実装されていますが、Unityでも同じなんでしょうか。
(Unityは使ったことなくて自分ではわからないのですが)
ある型に対して複数の箇所で取得したTypeが同一インスタンスであることはあるようですが、常に保証されるものなのかどうかちょっとわかっていません。

確実に等価性を判定できる「typeof(T).Equals(typeof(NullData))」でも結果は同じでしょうか？

それでも結果が同じであれば、Tが実際にはNullDataのインスタンスではなく、NullDataの派生型という可能性はないでしょうか。